# Create template for abstract procedures in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is more of a design issue with Visual Studio [>=2010].

Example: When you implement IDisposed in a VB environment, in the body of `Public Sub Dispose` there are numerous comments and a branch about how to do it. Also the field `disposed` is automaticaly inserted to the Class.

Now when I design an Interface or abstract Class, is there a way to define some kind of 'template' for each abstract procedure/property body, containing comments or even branches/loops?

**Edit:**
Now i realize that the C# environment has a different approach to these templates/snippets, but i'd like to make them available for developers in both environments.

These code snippets should be inserted preferebly when using `Implement Interface` or `Implement abstract Class` or when TABing after selecting an overridable procedure.

**Edit2:**
Ok, the Snipped Editor did indeed provide a reasonable solution.
Essentially i have to update my custom snippets for each target instance of VS at the path
`C:\%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio %VSVER%\%ENV%\Snippets\%LANG%\...`

I hoped there was a way to provide VS with the snippets via the referenced Assembly/Resource only.*

Comment: Check out my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543426/automatically-insert-comments-in-c-code/14543594#14543594). I think you should be able to do it this way as well.

Comment: Are you talking about [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx) where you can define your own snippet and Visual Studio pauses at each section to allow you to fill in the individual sections manually (such as when you type `if` and then hit TAB twice)?

Comment: How are you getting these fields to appear?  Normally when you implement IDisposable it just implements a single method.  Only VB.Net actually generates a field and comments about implementation IIRC

Comment: The code snippets look promising, i'm going to check those out

Comment: @BobbyDigital does the Snippet Editor work in a C# environment?

Comment: As far as I know. I think what the op in the link I provided was eluding to that.

Comment: @BobbyDigital yeah :D went straight to the developers site and there I only saw VB code, then after trying it i quickly discovered that the software is reasonably generic in that regard.
Regardless: It provided a solution for my needs for now :) Thank you.